# Android: change button id of buttons added using for loop?

Tags: android, button, android-studio

Ok basically I am currently creating an app, and there is an activity where I have many edit text views and image views displayed in a scrollview, so I add a delete button underneath each element, using a for loop. However, when I delete one of the elements using the delete button, I need to change the key of each element under the currently deleted by subtracting one to it. Now, this works well, but when I try to change the key of the delete buttons, so that each delete button now references the id-changed element, it doesn't seem to work in my app.

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)//create a delete button for every element in activity
    {
        final int bkey=500+i+1;
        final int key=i+1;
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(bkey);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LinearLayout myLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
                SharedPreferences id = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAM, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor idedit = id.edit();
                if (id.getBoolean(""+key+"img",false)==true){
                    ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(key);
                    Button b=(Button)findViewById(bkey);
                    myLayout.removeView(img);
                    myLayout.removeView(b);
                }
                else {
                    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(key);
                    Button b = (Button) findViewById(bkey);
                    myLayout.removeView(b);
                    myLayout.removeView(et);
                }
                if (key!=length) {
                    for (int i = key; i < (length); i++) {
                        int x = i + 1;
                        int temp=500+i;
                        int butkey=500+i+1;
                        if (id.getBoolean("" + x + "img", false) == false) {
                            EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(x);
                            Button b=(Button) findViewById(butkey);//This is what I tried
                            b.setId(temp);
                            t.setId(i);
                        } else {
                            ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(x);
                            im.setId(i);

                        }
                    }
                }
                if (key!=length) {
                    for (int i = key; i < (length); i++) {
                        int temp = i + 1;
                        int size = i + 100;
                        int tempsize = 100 + temp;
                        idedit.putString("" + i, id.getString("" + temp, null));
                        idedit.putInt("" + size, id.getInt("" + tempsize, 0));
                        idedit.putBoolean("" + i + "img", id.getBoolean("" + temp + "img", true));
                    }
                }

                length--;
                idedit.putInt("num",length);

                idedit.commit();

            }
        });
    }
```

I know its hard to understand out of context but if there is anything you might notice that could help me I would be very grateful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in list view or RECYCLE VIEW make a custome list view with text and image and button and when ever the button pressed the list will be deleted from the list of array.Hope this will help you